# disable all the dates before specific date KendoUI with asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date, kendo-ui

I have an MVC Application with `Kendo UI`. I have two date picker: from/to

the "to date" should disable all the values smaller than the "From date" value.

I wrote this JavaScript code:

```
function AktivVonChange() {
    debugger;
    var startDate = $("#AktivVon").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    $("#AktivBis").kendoDatePicker({
        value: startDate,
        disableDates: function(date) {
            if (date && compareDates(date, startDate)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

function compareDates(date, startDate) {
    if (startDate.getDate() === date.getDate() && startDate.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && startDate.getYear() === date.getYear()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it does not disable the values and I am receiving no errors. any help?

another question:

I have more than one date picker in multiple pages that they have to validate the same logic. is there is a way to add this code in layout one time for all without any edit to the `kendo`? like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add on change to all "From date"
});
```

thank you

Comment: have you checked this :http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/rangeselection

Comment: yes I did and still do not work

Comment: Take a look at this [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ojucE/53) and see if it helps.